# Is multiple download of music/video files possible on Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, download

Does anyone know which API/Library I can use to make multiple downloads of music/video happen at same time onto phonegap ios/Android app. I'm looking at both the simple and advanced API. I'm kinda lost in all of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am building a Mobile App on Phonegap which should allow user to download the music/video files from the web services.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely want to look into the [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) function.

As this function is run asynchronously (hence the callbacks), you should be completely able to download multiple at a time, and store them on to the device.

The simplest form for downloading would be

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/somefile");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, Thanks a ton for the quick help! Regards Rajeev

Comment: @NeeravShah: You should probably check out the [`onprogess` callback](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_onprogress). This will give you the percentage. To make a **Progress bar** depends on your UI Library.

Comment: Jamine I had tried to use it but the issue is i am downloading multiple files and in the progress bar it shows variation i.e sometime it increase then it decreases then again  increases